# Upload video on YouTube channel without end users login prompt using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-data-api

I want use Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 for video upload on YouTube.
My requirement is Upload video on YouTube channel without end users login prompt.
So please let me know where there is some method where i can validate the user at server side and upload video directly to my channel in YouTube.
I want to implement in MVC C# application

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadVideo(HttpPostedFileBase video, UploadVideoInfo info)
  {
    try
    {
      var httpPostedFile = Request.Files[0];
      if (httpPostedFile != null)
      {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
          credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
              GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
              //This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
              //authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
              new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
              "user",
              CancellationToken.None
          );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
          HttpClientInitializer = credential,
          ApplicationName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
      });

      var videos = new Video();
      videos.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
      videos.Snippet.Title = info.VideoTitle;
      videos.Snippet.Description = info.VideoDescription;
      videos.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
      videos.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
      videos.Status = new VideoStatus();
      videos.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "public" or "unlisted"
      var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(videos, "snippet,status", video.InputStream, "video/*");
      videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
      videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

      await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();

    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

  }
  return View();
  }
  void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
  {
    switch (progress.Status)
    {
      case UploadStatus.Uploading:
      Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
      break;

      case UploadStatus.Failed:
      Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
      break;
    }
  }

  void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
  }
```